# AttributeError: 'Table' object has no attribute 'table' in flask sqlalchemy association table

Tags: python, sqlite, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I am trying to create cart and order feature in my project. I have two tables regarding users and products which sqlalchemy models are following

```
class Users(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key = True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(50), unique = True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(50), unique = True)
    password_hash = db.Column(db.String(500), unique = True)
    address = db.Column(db.String(50))
    cart_items = db.relationship('Products', secondary = cart_items, backref = 'user_cart')
    orders = db.relationship('Products', secondary = orders, backref = 'user_order')

class Products(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key = True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(50), unique = True)
    desc = db.Column(db.String(350))
    price = db.Column(db.Integer)
```

I am trying to create association tables of cart and orders with one extra column in both the tables 'quantity'.

the association table code I have written is as following

```
orders = db.Table(
    'order',
    db.Column('user_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('users.id')),
    db.Column('product_id', db.Integer), db.ForeignKey('products.id'),
    db.Column('quantity', db.Integer)
)


cart_items = db.Table(
    'cart_items',
    db.Column('user_id',db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('users.id')),
    db.Column('product_id',db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('products.id')),
    db.Column('quantity', db.Integer)
)
```

When I have only one association table cart_items the tables get created without any error. But when I try creating the orders association table as well, while importing the Users and Products class to the repl by writing the code

```
from model import Users, Products
```

I get the error

```
AttributeError: 'Table' object has no attribute 'table'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try editing your code to this. I think you had an error on orders table.

```
orders = db.Table(
    'order',
    db.Column('user_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('users.id')),
    db.Column('product_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('products.id')),
    db.Column('quantity', db.Integer)
)


cart_items = db.Table(
    'cart_items',
    db.Column('user_id',db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('users.id')),
    db.Column('product_id',db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('products.id')),
    db.Column('quantity', db.Integer)
)
```